# Kafka Producer and Consumer Info

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics

I am trying to create a tool that can kill kafka producers and consumers randomly in order to simulate production environment. Is there a way to find the active producers and consumers in a kafka cluster? I want to exactly know which thread in which host is acting as the producer or the consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I started by getting the I.P. of at least one kafka broker from the HDP cluster.
2. I checked the open connections on the kafka broker on its specified port (by default it is 6667) and retrieved the IP addresses of the connected machines.
3. Using their IP Addresses, I found out the processes that are connected to the kafka broker.

Thus, I figured out the machines that are kafka producers and consumers.

Comment: This is interesting.  I am looking to do something similar.  It would be interesting to see some of the code you used to make this happen.

Comment: I don't have the code for this now, but I used netstat on Kafka broker machines to figure out which other machines have opened connections with 6667 port and retrieved the process ID from those connected machines using the port of the producer or consumer process